# how to find a number with max divisors from a set of input numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code to find the number with max divisors, but in the case with equal divisors like **672** and **8388608** which both of them have **24** divisors the code cannot select the biggest number and just return the first number with the more number of divisors. In that example, the code returns 672 while it is vivid that 8388608 is much bigger than 672!
please help me to modify my code.
thank you in advance.

```
def divisors(x):
    c = 0
    for i in range (1,x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            c += 1
    return c

m = 0
count = 0
for i in range (20):
    a = int(input())
    if divisors(a) > count:
        m = a
        count = divisors(a)

print(m,'',count)
```

Comment: Check your indentation.  I think I corrected it.

Comment: You know that there is a much faster way to find the number of divisors of a number than enumerating all the integers between 1 and n.  I'm surprised you had the patience to find the number of factors 8388608.  Get the prime factorization of n.  Let's say it is `(p1 ** a1)(p2 ** a2)(p3 ** a3) ...` Then the number of factors is `(a1 + 1)(a2 + 1)(a3 + 1)...`.  
`8388608 = 2**23.  (23 + 1) = 24`.  `672 = 2**5 * 3**1 * 7 ** 1.  6 * 2 * 2 = 24.`

Comment: any number divided by greater than half its value going to be less than 1. so you dont have to iterate thru all the numbers, just half the numbers only. And you need to prime numbers from that list. That gives you a much faster answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code will collect the maximum number of divisors in a list, resetting the list if a greater number is found, and appending to the list otherwise.  If there are multiple numbers with the same number of divisors, you'll get a list of them:

```
def divisors(x):
    c = 0
    for i in range (1,x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            c += 1
    return c

m = []
count = 0
inputs = 767,665,999,895,907,796,561,914,719,819,555,529,672,933,882,869,801,660,879,985
for a in sorted(inputs):
    d = divisors(a)
    if d == count:
        m.append(a)
    elif d > count:
        m = [a]
        count = d
print(m,'',count)
```

Output:

```
[660, 672]  24
```

If you just want the biggest number, use `max(m)` in the final print instead.